# customize jQuery Validation message and markup

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following form

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="#">
    <div class="fields">
        <fieldset class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <legend class="ui-widget ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">&nbsp;Customer properties&nbsp;</legend>
            <input type="hidden" id="CustomerID" name="CustomerID"  value="${CustomerID}" />
            <br />
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td><label for="Code">Customer Code</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="Code" name="Code" value="${Code}" class="ui-widget-content" style="width:140px" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td><label for="CustomerName">Name</label></td>
                <td><textarea id="CustomerName" rows="2" cols="40" name="CustomerName" class="ui-widget-content">${CustomerName}</textarea></td>
            </tr>
            ...
            </table>
            <br />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:right; padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;">
        <input type="submit" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" class="button" value="Save" />
        <input type="button" id="btnCancel" name="btnCancel" class="button" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
</form>
```

on which I apply jQuery validation through the following code

```
$('#myform').validate({
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.html($('<img alt="" src="error.png" />').attr('title', error.html())).insertAfter(element);
    },
    rules: {
        ...
    },
    messages: {
        ...
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        saveCustomer(form);
    }
});
```

This code works very nice the first time is being executed (when I press the submit button) and the image appear regularly immediately after the input text. Anyway when I tab to another edit the image disappear and I can see again the text around the edit. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

see [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions)- you can use the `errorElement` option to create your custom error display,
invalidHandler method (I think) to disable the group messages part.
you can use `errorPlacement` to control how the error is displayed (untested example):

```
$("#myform").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
       element.append('<img source=".." title="' + error.text() +'" />');
   }
 })
```

this should create an image with a tooltip containing the error message.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please show or link a code sample?

Comment: http://mitchlabrador.com/2010/11/05/how-to-change-the-way-jquery-validate-handles-error-messages/

Comment: Ok. I have been able to understand how the errorPlacement function works. I am still not able to understand how to use the other options to create an image element :(

Comment: @sJhonny-: thanks for the answer. thanks to your first answer I have created what you suggest here with a slightly different code and edited my question accordingly. This works but there still are some problems when the validation is fired after a `blur()` event. Have a look at my question edit for details. thanks

Comment: can you specify exactly which element disappears when blur occurs?

Comment: After having added to the `errorPlacement` function, when I load the screen and press the save button I can see that everything works and the image is correctly added to the invalid field. Anyway if I tab through the fields, when a field loose its focus the image disappear and is substituted from the error message (as the default validation works)

Comment: @Lorenzo: nothing comes to mind right now... perhaps you should ask another question, posting your new code and the new problem